# Add end node to linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Can't seem to pin down what I'm missing here. I know how to properly insert a new node at the beginning of my linked list:

```
void InsertBeginning(int val) {
        Node *n = new Node();   
        n->data = val;             
        n->next = A;         

        A = n;      
        DisplayList(); //prints list
}
```

And now I wish to do the same thing but at the end of my list, so then I made this:

```
void AddNode(int val) {
        Node *n = new Node();
        n->data = val;
        n->next = A;

        //finds last empty node
        while (n->next != NULL) {
            n = n->next;
        }

        A = n;

        DisplayList();
}
```

But all this does is delete everything but my first node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walk down the list and then add the new node.  Note that there is no need to modify `A`, which presumably points to the head of the list, because it doesn't change.

```
void AddNode(int val) {
    Node *n = new Node();
    n->data = val;
    n->next = NULL;
    Node *pnt = A;

    // If list is empty, new node becomes first node
    if (!pnt) {
        A = n;
        return;
    }

    //finds last empty node
    while (pnt->next != NULL) {
        pnt = pnt->next;
    }

    pnt->next = n;

    DisplayList();
}
```

Comment: That edit does not even compile, let alone do the right thing. E: There you go. ;)

Comment: Also maybe call the DisplayList() before returning for empty list . ;)

Comment: If you keep track of the `tail` node of the list, inserts at the end become much faster and more efficient, as you don't have to traverse the list anymore: `void AddNode(int val) { Node *n = new Node(); n->data = val; n->next = NULL; if (!head) { head = n; } if (tail) { tail->next = n; } tail = n; DisplayList(); }`

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom that allows one to handle all cases uniformly (i.e. avoid special processing for the "very first node in the list" situation) works as follows

```
void AddNode(int val) 
{
  Node *n = new Node();
  n->data = val;
  // Assuming that `n->next` is already null

  Node **pnext = &A;
  for (; *pnext != NULL; pnext = &(*pnext)->next);

  *pnext = n;

  DisplayList();
}
```